# Mount Command Yes, Fstab No

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, mount, network-shares

Ubuntu Server 14.04

When I execute this command the share is mounted!
sudo mount -t cifs //localhost/share /media/sharemount -o port=5454,username="",password=""

However when I try to mount permanently, I get this error: " Can not access a needed shared library"

//localhost/share /media/sharemount cifs username="",password="",port=5454,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0

What am I missing????? Thanks!

I did try installing windbind but it did not work: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=288534

Comment: Where if your fstab do you mention cifs?  Maybe Ubuntu figures that out based on the syntax?  Or maybe it defaults to thinking that means NFS?  Another thought: if you load from the fstab, are you doing that by using mount -a?  Or does the problem only exist when you're trying to auto-mount stuff during the system boot?

Comment: I had cifs in fstab. I accidentally left it out in my post above. Edit Above. So yes I have CIFS in my fstab mount. Yes I am using mount -a and I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it my self.
The issue causing the error is iocharset=utf8. I simply deleted that part and mount was successful. HOWEVER if like me you installed a min image of Ubuntu the program to understand utf8 was not installed. So this solution will resolve the issue as well: [Unicode Characters in Ubuntu Server](https://superuser.com/questions/682362/unicode-characters-in-ubuntu-server)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check if you have mount.cifs installed. 
If you don't, then :

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

More details here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: I voted down because I would of had to have cifs-utils in order to mount with cifs as I successfully did above. The problem is with fstab.

Comment: I don't think so. I think if you have smb installed you can mount cifs manually, cifs-utils comes in when you mount with fstab. It happened to me not long ago. Did you check if you have it intalled ?